# Uncommon mosfet usage

Tags: mosfet

Occasionally I am faced with a problem where I am faced with a device that needs two of it's inputs to be shorted together for something to activate (Think smoke machine or gate motor).

This is the circuit I have been using:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZz6y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is that the resistance of the mosfet goes down when a signal is applied which simulates the short circuit. My concern is that this feels very unconventional.

Is this an acceptable method of doing this? are there more professional methods?

note: it isn't as simple as sending a '0' signal. That often isn't how these systems work.

thanks.

Comment: You should really only do that if you have a common ground. You would be wiser to use a relay for the isolation benefits.

Comment: output2 is grounded.

Comment: or an opto-isolator

Comment: Anyway, it resembles the open-drain output.

Comment: Also be aware a MOSFET includes a big fat diode in there. Wire it up the wrong way around and it will not work.

Comment: @Trevor_G Ya, i figured that out after several hours of confusion

Comment: Won't work with a N-MOSFET if the ground is common with the  device because the source is going to ground, and the signal from 1 will go to ground (turn to 0V) instead of activating something at input 2. One way is to try to use input 2 as COM. But it's risky, I mean really not conventional.  Or use a P-MOSFET instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, it depends.

If the gate drive is floating this will work fine, though note it has a polarity due to the intrinsic diode in the MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foJDex.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This however.. **will not**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPpcCD.png)</sup>

If you need to do multiples, you would need a common ground everywhere.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPm9Jy.png)</sup>

A better method would be to use a relay or better still an [opto-coupled MOSFET](https://ca.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/Optocouplers-Photocouplers/MOSFET-Output-Optocouplers/_/N-awss6/).

[image]

The latter is also bi-polar due to the back-to-back MOSFETS which block the diodes.